# How to update txt file in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to update a line in a txt file which contains property-values pairs, where a property is between square brackets and its value in the line below. This is an example file: On top of that i want to ignore the comment lines started with '#'. On the other hand what if i want to add comments to the comment line?

```
#===========================
#===========================
[system]
# comment 
programming 
#===========================
[information] 
#
application
```

In this example, ´system´ is a property and ´programming´ its value. The same way, ´information´ is another property and ´application´ its value.

I want to call my function with a property-value pair and update the corresponding values in the txt file. Until now I have the following:

```
fh = fopen(filename,'r');
 fh= fopen(filename,'w');
 while ~feof 
 line = fgetl(fh);
 if(line(1) == '[') && (line(end) == ']') 
value = lower(line(2:end-1));
```

Then I will compare the 'value' with my input to check if it matches with property. If so I should update the next line with the new input. Finally I have to write to the original file.

For this sample txt how can I update the word 'programming' to 'system information'?

Comment: Do you want to replace the word with the contents in the brackets? Do you want to replace all occurrences, or perhaps just the first? Why not simply use notepad for that?

Comment: Hallo, Eitant. The intention is to update the value(i.e content below) the property( content in brackets). whenever i get the line with the brackets i should be able to update(over write) the value.

Comment: A little more context will really help. How do you parse the file? Can you show some code (only the relevant part)?

Comment: sorry for the mistake :)

Comment: So, If I've understood correctly, a word in brackets is a property and the content below a word in brackets is the value of this property? But I haven't understood what you have to replace and with which value. Please, give us more context so we can better help you.

Comment: @Digna, sure u r correct. the intetion is, whenever there is input argument with property and value pair, the property value should be updated to the new value .like: myfile('property','value'),  eg. value = 'user'

Comment: So, just to make sure I've understood it correctly before I answer: your function receives a property-value pair and you want to update those values to the file. For example, in this case your file contains property=system value=programming and property=information and value=application. If you call the function with the parameters: property=system value=user, the file should be updated to contain: [system]
user 
[information] 
application   Is this correct?

Comment: That is right, @ Digna.  Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
function [] = updateFile( fileName, propName, newProbVal )
%
% update file fileName, replacing the value of propName with newPropVal
%
% all inputs are strings
%
rfh = fopen( fileName, 'r' ); % read handle
tname = tempname(); % temporary file name
wfh = fopen( tname, 'w' );

% read line by line
foundFlag = false;
line = fgetl( rfh );
while ischar(line)
    if foundFlag
        fprintf( wfh, '%s\r\n', newProbVal );
        foundFlag = false;
    else
        fprintf( wfh, '%s\r\n', line );
    end
    tks = regexp( line, ['^\[',propName,'\]'] );
    foundFlag = ~isempty(tks);
    line = fgetl( rfh );    
end
fclose( rfh );
fclose( wfh );
movefile( tname, fileName, 'f' ); % rename temp file name
```

Comment: Hallo @ shai , thanks for your reaction. your code didn't seem to work. The orginal file become empty instead .

Comment: @ shai ..again thanks for your support . even you have made corrections ,both temp and the original files are still empty.

Comment: made another small correction - hope I got it this time. If you can debug this - please make sure the loop is being executed...

Comment: thank you very much . it works.  one more thing, the output seems to be in one row , how can i transpose it so that i will have one column instead of the one row.

Comment: I added a newline char (`\n`) to prints - this may have the desired effect. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @ shai, thanks for ur fast reaction. but it didn't work with the new line. :)